# Make the ArrayList add thread-safe without using thread safe collections

Tags: java, multithreading

I've made a code executing 4 threads that would add 5000 integers each to a list.
At the end of the execution, I'm supposed to have 4 * 5000 elements in my list.
But I end up with only 1190 (the number may change)

Here the code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ConcurentList {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int range = 5000;
        int nbThreads = 4;

        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        ThreadSafeArrayList<Integer> integerThreadSafeArrayList = new ThreadSafeArrayList<>(integers);
        Thread[] arrayOfThread = new Thread[nbThreads];
        for (int i = 0; i < nbThreads; i++)
        {
            arrayOfThread[i] = new Thread(() -> {
                for (int j = 0; j < range; j++) {
                    integerThreadSafeArrayList.add(1);
                }
            });
            arrayOfThread[i].start();
            System.out.println("Le thread " + i + " ended.");
        }
        System.out.println("Size of the list " + integerThreadSafeArrayList.getSize());
    }
}
```

And ThreadSafeArrayList :

```
import java.util.List;

public class ThreadSafeArrayList<T> {
    private List<T> list;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public ThreadSafeArrayList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public boolean add(T element) {
        boolean add;
        synchronized (lock) {
            add = list.add(element);
        }
        return add;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

I understand that arraylist isn't thread safe and therefor the predict the behaviour of the execution but since I used a synchronized on private final lock I expected to obtain the normal behaviour.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

That is because, when this gets executed,

```
System.out.println("Size of the list " + integerThreadSafeArrayList.getSize());
```

the other threads are still running and doing the work that you have asked them to do.

To see the actual result, add this line just before the last statement.

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
```

The output I can see now is:

```
Le thread 0 ended.
Le thread 1 ended.
Le thread 2 ended.
Le thread 3 ended.
Size of the list 20000
```

Comment: I'm so dumb... Ty

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues:

1. You need to join started threads to let them finish their work before method main ends.

   ```
   for (Thread thread : arrayOfThread) {
       thread.join();
   }
   ```
2. Method getSize is not thread safe, thus you need to use synchronization:

   ```
   public int getSize() {
       synchronized (lock) {
           return list.size();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

wait result

```
for (int i = 0; i < nbThreads; i++) {
    arrayOfThread[i].join();
}
```